# RAM patch for Windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, 32-bit

I have to use Windows 7 32 bit in a computer, which I need to use a software which just works with this operating system unfortunately.

I have 8GB RAM installed I applied the patch developed by Unawave to let the OS see all the RAM installed. This is the link of the patch:

http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/32-bit-ram-barrier.html?lang=EN

However, I was also told that **Windows 7 32 bit limits the usage of RAM for each application at 2 GB**.
Does this patch remove also this limit?
In case it doesn't, do you know a way to get rid of this limit and to use at least 4GB for application, which I think it's the maximum possible for a 32 OS (as 2^32=4GB)?

Thanks a lot for letting me know.

E.

Comment: A third party hack to bypass a physical kernal level protection mechanism is not a patch...

Answer (score 2):

**The only way for a 32-bit application to access more than 2 GB of memory is for the application to explicitly support it.**

One method is the `/3GB` boot flag. This enables a “Large Address Aware” application to use 3 GB of memory. It can cause various complications, though, because of limited kernel memory space. You can turn the LAA flag on for any application at your own risk. **This also means 3 GB is the maximum amount of regularly usable memory for any 32-bit application on a 32-bit operating system. There are no exceptions.** Official documentation is also available [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=889654).

The other method is “[Address Windowing Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Windowing_Extensions)”, which, again, the application needs to support. It cannot be manually enabled and is largely irrelevant for consumers. It involves multiple sets of memory which the application can switch to, hence “Windowing”.

Your patch illegally modifies Windows (though MS probably doesn’t care) and force-enables [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension). This can lead to problems with device drivers not supporting it, which is why PAE is (basically) disabled by default on consumer versions of Windows.

Comment: Dear Daniel, thank you very much for your answer. What you said is very interesting. What I'd like to do is to maximize the performance of this application. How can I see if this application supports LAA or AWE? What is the risk that I run? I can still create a restore point and go back to the previous version of the OS, can't I? In any case I have 8GB RAM installed, which now the computer seems to see completely, so I should have enough memory to run risks... Thank you again for letting me know

Comment: Well, basically, it’s like this: Your applications don’t support AWE. They may support LAA. You can modify `.exe` files and enable the LAA flag. They may run. They may crash. It’s not really about the amount of physical memory available. It won’t damage your hardware or data—unless the program editing it crashes, of course.

Comment: Can you send me the instructions on how to activate LAA or AWE please? Thank you

Comment: Like I said, you cannot “enable” AWE. As for LAA, there’s [this tool](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/large-address-aware.112556/)—that I have neither used nor tested, so YMMV.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Is there a way in which I can formally thank you? (like giving you a rating for your help)?

Comment: No, now that the question is closed that is impossible. That’s just how it is. ;)

Comment: I think that the Unawave "patch" that I mentioned in my original message also expands the RAM usage of every process to 3GB, I'd like to make sure of it. I tried to email him, but he's not replied to me yet... Do you know anything about it?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. This change always requires modifying the `.exe` file.

Comment: I understand, then does it mean that the limit is still 2GB per process? If so tomorrow I'll try to use the tool you sent me and see if it works, thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Do I have to restart the system after I've used the LAA app you sent me?

Comment: No. You have to start the modified `.exe` file. That’s all.

Comment: In addition, how can I check if the exe supports LAA?

Comment: Sorry to write to you again, but do I have to do if I wanted to use address windowing extensions?