# How to make use of an extra RAM slot?

Tags: laptop, memory, computer-building

My computer already has 4 GB of RAM, and cannot make use of more than about 3 GB, but there is an extra slot still available for another chip. Is there any other kind of chip that can be put there in place of memory serving some other function? Or can I add another memory chip and let the computer utilize this in some alternative way?

Comment: You have 32-bit OS? Can you enable PAE?

Comment: Switching to 64 bit is probably well worth it, despite the initial effort

Comment: You cannot use it for anything except increasing the amount of physical memory your system can use.

Comment: It is a 32-bit OS. I think the CPU only allows for running 32-bit. I do not really need more RAM, but am more interested in knowing if their are other functions for this slot.

Comment: Are you sure about the processor? [The last intel 32bit procs came out a decade ago](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors#32-bit_processors:_NetBurst_microarchitecture).

Comment: It is an [Intel Core Duo T2400](http://ark.intel.com/products/27235/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2400-2M-Cache-1_83-GHz-667-MHz-FSB). According to the link, "Instruction Set: 32-bit".

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/830594/ram-patch-for-windows-7-32bit

Answer (score 1):

Acording to [this](http://www.storage-switzerland.com/blog/entries/2011/11/29_Empty_DIMM_Slots_Can_be_Best_Place_for_SSDs.html), maybe you can use it for **SSD.**
Also you can use it as [RAM Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) but I suppouse that that is not what you where looking for.

After google it a little bit, I am prety sure that you can use SSD in your DIMM slot, and they  will retain data even after you’ve powered down.

You can find some aditioanl info [here](http://www.sandisk.com/enterprise/ulltradimm-ssd/), or watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGfpdciV9B4).
As these products are by [SanDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SanDisk) I think it can be used as relevant, although I have never use SSD in this fasion.

*In addition, as per comment by ramhound I have updated links so they are less than one year old*

Comment: Those links describe using the SSDs in an availabale socket, but only in the context of a system that can address and use that memory.  It isn't clear that at 32 bit system could utilize this when the maximum RAM is already installed.

Answer (score -1):

The slot is designed to put only a RAM module, restricted to the speed of the RAM bus your hardware use.